# What is the correct regular expression for this NSString in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I have a string that I am confused about how to make a regular expression with:

```
<a href="/pins/abc-1234-xyz/"
```

The parts that are ALWAYS the same are:

```
<a href="/pins/
```

and

```
/"
```

The junk in between can be `a-z A-Z 0-9` and the dash (minus) character `-`

Is this correct?

```
regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<a href=\"/pins/([^""]*)/"")";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is close, but you need to escape all your doublequotes, and remove the unmatched parenthesis:

```
regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<a href=\"/pins/([^\"]*)/\"";
```